# angular animation not working

Tags: angularjs, css, animation

I am new AngularJS.I am not able to apply animations to my text and button. I am not getting any error in the console. i have no idea where its going wrong. I want different animations to my text and button. I have provided css animation link in the html. here is my html page. please help me to know whether i am applying animation in a right way or not .

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bounceOut.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="zoomIn.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h3 class="bounceOut">I am</h3> </div>
<button type="submit" class="OptionButton zoomIn">
Submit
</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
  app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my bounceOut animation css code

```
@keyframes bounceOut {
  20% {
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  50%, 55% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
}
.bounceOut {
  animation-name: bounceOut;
}
```

here is my zoomIn animation css code

```
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.zoomIn {
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are usgin css3 animation and not angularjs animation. If I percive wrong please tell me but this should work,

```
/* Styles go here */

.zoomIn {
  animation: zoomInf 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: zoomInf 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes zoomInf {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoomInf {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@keyframes bounceOutf {
  20% {
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }
  50%,
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes  bounceOutf {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }
  50%,
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }
}


.bounceOut {
  animation: bounceOutf 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounceOutf 5s infinite;
}
```

Comment: its working properly but i want bounceInLeft animation for my text. will you please help me this animation.

Comment: Refer this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/74QLiEfv6mtfqeNKwjUJ/) demostrating this

Comment: I tried the code its working fine. I changed it to the bounceInRight as i want the bounceInRight animation. But the only problem with this is its bouncing back to the starting place. i want it to stop in the center.

Comment: @keyframes bounceInRightfs {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.;
    transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);  
  }
  to {
  opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
  }
}
.bounceInRight {
  right: 400px;
  animation: bounceInRightfs 3s ;
  -webkit-animation: bounceInRightfs 3s ;
  -moz-animation: bounceInRightfs 3s ;
}

Comment: Its actually coming to center `@-webkit-keyframes bounceInRightfs {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 1);
  }
}

.bounceInRight {
  width:500px;
  border: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  animation: bounceInRightfs 3s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounceInRightfs 3s infinite;
  -moz-animation: bounceInRightfs 3s infinite;
}`

Comment: animation is not working. only horizontal line is coming below the text

Comment: please create a jsfiddle and share with me, I can take a look